# Count Instances Until Value Repeats

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a list/array/series of booleans, and I want a list of the same length that contains `NaNs` wherever there was a `False` value in the original, and on `True` indices I want to plug the number of `False` elements until the next `True`. If there is no subsequent `True` than the last "count" should be `np.inf`.
For example:

```
input: [False, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, True, False , False, False]
output: [NaN, NaN, 0, 2, NaN, NaN, 1, NaN, np.inf, NaN, NaN, NaN]
```

Of course, I could iterate over the array/list and count (better to start the iteration from the end in that case). I'm interested in a vectorized implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) array:

```
a = np.array([False, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False])

# identify True
idx = np.nonzero(a)[0]
# array([2, 3, 6, 8])

# set up output
out = np.full_like(a, np.nan, dtype=float)

# replace first n-1 True with distance to next
out[idx[:-1]] = np.diff(idx)-1
# last True (if any) is np.inf
out[idx[-1:]] = np.inf
```

Output:

```
array([nan, nan,  0.,  2., nan, nan,  1., nan, inf, nan, nan, nan])
```

Assuming a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) Series with a range index:

```
s = pd.Series([False, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, True, False , False, False])

out = pd.Series(index=s.index)
out[idx] = (-s[s].index.diff(-1)-1).fillna(np.inf)
```

Or more complex approach with a `groupby`

```
s = pd.Series([False, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, True, False , False, False])

# reverse Series
s2 = s[::-1]
# mask last True/Falses
m2 = s2.shift(fill_value=False).cummax()

# compute distance to next True
out = s2.groupby(s2.cumsum()).cumcount().shift()[::-1].where(s2)
# mask last True with np.inf
out[s2 & ~ m2] = np.inf
```

Output:

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     0.0
3     2.0
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     1.0
7     NaN
8     inf
9     NaN
10    NaN
11    NaN
dtype: float64
```